# Reopen request 855983

Tags: support, status-completed, reopen-request

I've now fixed the title of my question so it is in line with the topic of home networking:

[Can a home PPPoE connection access all websites, regardless of the site infrastructure's MTU settings?](https://superuser.com/q/855983/245640)

Any chance this could be reviewed for reopening?

Comment: @ram Yes there is.

Comment: @Ramhound: Any chance you could expand on that?

Comment: Deleted comments make this very hard to follow :(